# Securing against scans

Tags: web-application, appsec, web-scanners

I have a VM which is exposed to the internet. I can see a lot of scans for `/azenv.php`, `/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php` and like in my server logs.

1. How do I protect from these scans?
2. Am I being targeted for a hack?
3. Is this a concern at all?

Comment: Welcome to the internet. The Internet is filled with automated scanners looking for what they can find. This is only a concern if you have those things exposed to the Internet.

Comment: Welcome to the Internet, where all sort of bots are constantly scanning for vulnerabilities. If you don't have such URLs, do nothing. If you are using the software, keep it up-to-date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Protecting a web app from unwanted vulnerability scanners](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/194006/protecting-a-web-app-from-unwanted-vulnerability-scanners), [How to defend against web server security scanners?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/157541/how-to-defend-against-web-server-security-scanners).